# Sort multiple type multidimension array by specific column

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimension String array. It contains numbers and strings. Is there any way to sort it by a specific integer column?
e.g. I have this:

1. Fox | 32 | One
2. Dog | 45 | Two
3. Cat | 34 | Three
4. Snake | 3 | Four

I want to sort this String array by integer column.
For example:

1. Dog | 45 | Two
2. Cat | 34 | Three
3. Fox | 32 | One
4. Snake | 3 | Four

I tried with this but it requires integer array.

```
Arrays.sort(temp, new Comparator<int[]>() {
@Override
public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
    return Integer.compare(o2[1], o1[1]);
}});
```

Comment: why don't you use an array of objects?

Comment: int[] o1, int[] o2 you say you have tow arrays type integer, i am sure if you change is to int o1 and int o2 everything will be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solve your issue: (updated)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] temp = {
        { "Fox", "32", "One" },
        { "Dog", "45", "Two" },
        { "Cat", "34", "Three" },
        { "Snake", "3", "Four" }
    };

    Arrays.sort(temp, new Comparator<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] row1, String[] row2) {
            return Integer.compare(
                    Integer.parseInt(row1[1]), Integer.parseInt(row2[1]));
        }
    });

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(temp));
}
```

Comment: really? you have row1 and row2 as object type and you cast them to integer at the end? it may work but it does not seem right to me

Comment: Yes, right way is to have special type for this row's entity and special comparator for it. But that solves answered case.

Comment: and it is not even clear to me how the op wants to sort the 2d array base on what?

Comment: It shows an exception (java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer)

Comment: Ok it works. So is it possible to show the results with descending order?

Comment: To invert sort order just swap row1[1] and row2[1].